# Is it possible to call a payable function within __callback of Oraclize?

Tags: go-ethereum, oracles, payable

I want to run an Oracle query periodically and my idea was to call `getUTCTimestamp(0)` for the first query where `getUTCTimestamp` is:

```
function getUTCTimestamp(uint256 delay) payable {
   oraclize_query(delay,"WolframAlpha", "Timestamp now");
}
```

and then inside the callback call `getUTCTimestamp(60)` to have a call every 60 seconds. The thing is that the call inside callback is never executed and I imagine that happens because no ether is supplied. Is this correct? Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any way to achieve what I want?**

Yes, *recursive queries* are ***very possible*** using Oraclize.

From the Oraclize documentation at [recursive queries](https://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start-recursive-queries):

> Smart contracts using Oraclize can be effectively autonomous by
>   implementing a new call to Oraclize into their __callback method. This
>   can be useful for implementing periodic updates of some on-chain
>   reference data, as with price feeds, or to periodically check for some
>   off-chain conditions.

Oraclize recommend to use this kind of queries with particular attention.

**The thing is that the call inside callback is never executed and I imagine that happens because no ether is supplied. Is this correct?**

Correct. Remember that with Oraclize only the first query is free. After the first you need to pay.You can find at this link more information about the prices: [Oraclize pricing](https://docs.oraclize.it/#pricing-advanced-datasources-call-fee).

What you need to do perform recursive queries is just ***provide your smart contract enough ether*** to pay for the Oraclize Query multiple times.

Comment: I have been using remix.ethereum.org to test oraclize in my smart contract which has some ether, but from your answer it seems that I would need to use real ether to achieve what I want. My understanding was that remix was just simulating everything and I could use "fake" ether.

Comment: Yes, remix is using fake ethers.

Comment: To clarify, Remix is mainly a testing tool, so use "fake" ethers. For recursive queries - you can copy and paste this recursive example in Remix, and test it: https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/KrakenPriceTicker.sol. If you use the JVM environment - which you can select under the "Run" section from the menu on the right - Remix will use only fake ethers, and provide you a fast way for testing smart contracts. Remember to launch the *Oraclize plugin* before deploying your contract and using its functions, under the "Settings" section from the menu on the right.

Comment: I tried to run that example but it is not working even though I supplied some ether to the smart contract. What happens is that only the first call is made and not the recursive ones. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you run the plugin from the "Settings" tab on the menu? It is the only way to make the Oraclize example work with the JavaScript Vm environment.You should see a window showing that the plugin is open. Please, remember to not close it when you perform the query, and to not open it multiple times

Comment: Yes I did that otherwise the first query would have failed as well.

Comment: Please note that Remix is not showing you what is happening behind. If you try to run the same example with "Environment: Injected Web3" instead of JavaScript VM, you could use etherscan to see that recursive queries are actually generated correctly. I just tested the recursive example previously linked and this will continue to perform recursive queries until it will run out of money: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa66ace1d551c34e092791e9b5a6253847fd3ead4